# How can I get object field descriptions to ouput with a Graphene GraphQL schema?

Tags: python, testing, graphql, graphene-python

I have my graphql schema implemented in graphene, with the a test object and schema object being:

```py
class Test(ObjectType):
    id = ID(description='Test ID')
    test_string = String(description='Test String')

schema = Schema(query=Query, subscription=Subscription, mutation=Mutation)
```

For testing and front end development purposes, I print out the schema using:

```py
from server.graphql_handler.schema import schema
print(schema)
```

This gives me something like this:

```
schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
    subscription: Subscription
}

type Test {
    id: ID
    test_string: String
}
```

My question being, is is possible to output the `Test` object fields' descriptions as well? Maybe something like:

```
type Test {
    """
    Test ID
    """"
    id: ID

    """
    Test String
    """
    test_string: String
}
```

Comment: Not able to understand.